# Bind click events to dynamically created html content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following jQuery command to bind the click event when the specific element is dynamically created.

```
$(".bill-remove-icon").live("click", function(){
$(this).parent().hide('slide',function(){$(this).parent().remove()});
});
```

But this code gives a firebug error :

```
TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here? if this code is wrong, pls suggest a better method to bind events to dynamically created elements.

Answer (score 3):

Live is deprecated, you have to use delegation with `.on()`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".bill-remove-icon", function(){
    $(this).parent().hide('slide',function(){$(this).parent().remove()});
});
```

Comment: roasted: Thanks! I figured that! :) Any way thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

`live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. You need to use `.on()`, which works a little differently than `live()` did. You can't attach the event handler to the dynamically injected element, you must attach it to an element which exists on page load, and *delegate* the event to the dynamically added element, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bill-remove-icon', function() {
   ...
});
```

You should change `document` for something closer to `bill-remove-icon`, so that the event doesn't bubble right the way up the DOM tree.

#### [See Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `live` it is deprecated.  Use `on`

```
$(".bill-remove-icon").on("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().hide('slide',function(){$(this).parent().remove()});
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/